# I would like to create a Dataframe from an updated API data OR iterating a dictionary using "for" loop

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to create a `dict` first, then a `dataframe` from this:

```
# timeline request (single)
timeline = trading.in_play_service.get_event_timeline(
    event_id=event_ids[0]
)
print(timeline)
for update in timeline.update_detail:
    print(
        update.update_type,
        update.elapsed_added_time,
        update.team_name,
        update.update_id,
        update.elapsed_regular_time,
        update.update_time,
    )  # view resources or debug to see all values available
```

Right now it only prints the updated data coming from the API of Betfair and I get this result:

```
EventTimeline
KickOff None None 9 1 2019-12-20 08:42:44.554000
YellowCard None Western United 37 22 2019-12-20 09:04:09.506000
YellowCard None Western Sydney Wanderers 51 30 2019-12-20 09:12:00.604000
YellowCard None Western Sydney Wanderers 65 38 2019-12-20 09:20:44.413000
FirstHalfEnd 2 None 84 45 2019-12-20 09:29:46.558000
SecondHalfKickOff None None 87 46 2019-12-20 09:45:46.177000
YellowCard None Western United 105 61 2019-12-20 10:00:55.977000
Goal None Western Sydney Wanderers 136 79 2019-12-20 10:19:18.448000
Goal None Western United 147 87 2019-12-20 10:27:16.620000
SecondHalfEnd 6 None 163 90 2019-12-20 10:35:56.159000
```

Any help with doing it? I am quite a beginner and trying to solve so many things by myself in my journey to automatize my trading. Any help appreciated and open for collaboration too.

Comment: Can you show me the output of print(timeline)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create an empty `DataFrame` like that:

```
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Update_time', 'Team_name', etc...])
```

then, you can fill the data in the dataFrame object :

```
for update in timeline.update_detail: 
    dfObj = dfObj.append({'Update_time':update.update_type , 'Team_name': update.team 
    , etc.})
```

After doing this, print the dataFrame object:

```
print("Dataframe Contens ", dfObj, sep='\n')
```

Now, you should see the dataFrame with your data. Note that tmy code will not work in this form (it is a bit pseudo). Furthermore, you should actually define the types of your columns in the dataFrame when initializing the dataFrame object.